# Not able to apply string to number custom directive on select input

Tags: angular, angular-directive

```
import { Directive, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from "@angular/core";
@Directive({
  selector: '[string-to-number]'
}) export class StringToNumberDirective {
  @Input() ngModel: any;
  @Output() ngModelChange = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.data);
    this.ngModelChange.emit(Number(this.ngModel));
  }
}
```

Whenever I am selecting drop down value the directive is not called. I need to be able to convert the string value of option to number and I know can do this with the help of pipe but looking forward for using directive.
Here Html & Ts file looks like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives:[StringToNumberDirective],
  template: `
  <select  [(ngModel)]="data" string-to-number>
      <option value="">Select Type</option>
      <option value="1000">Apple</option>
      <option value="2000">Mango</option>
  <select>
  <p>{{d}}</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public data="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a directive for that. Use `ngValue` like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="data">
  <option value="">Select Type</option>
  <option [ngValue]="1000">Apple</option>
  <option [ngValue]="2000">Mango</option>
</select>
```

Check the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgSelectOption) for more info.

Working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w1d9db?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I know that I can do this but the requirement is to use directive. This is just an example but this directive can be used in many places. I need to find the solution using directive.